# How to build on a host when running Jenkins inside a Docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker

I am running a Jenkins instance within a Docker container, and it is connected to a Bitbucket repository. When something changes in the online repository, Jenkins downloads the new source. Based on the new source, I want to create a new Docker image, but that needs to happen on the host since it is where I have Docker installed.

I haven't figured out how can I run something on the host, but at the same time I understand that Docker is used for isolating processes, so this is by design. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I would create a separate [Jenkins slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) that maps to either the host running Jenkins, or a separate host that has Docker installed. Then run your job to create Docker images on the slave rather than the master.

The documentation for the [official Jenkins Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) has details on how to connect up a slave.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to use Jenkins in Docker so that I wouldn't need to install it on the host. Installing a Jenkins slave on the host defeats the purpose.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Adding a node as a slave does not involve installing anything, at least on most linux systems. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure Nodes -> New node, change the Launch method to *Launch slave agents via ssh* and fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Docker from a host inside your Jenkins container. You need to install Docker on the container and then map the host's Docker socket descriptor.

A sample Dockerfile that will achieve this could looks like this:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.102

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    software-properties-common

# Docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable" && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce && \
    usermod -aG docker,staff jenkins

# Set SUID to run docker as root
RUN chmod g+s /usr/bin/docker

USER jenkins
```

To run a container based on this image with Docker working, you need to map the `docker.sock` file descriptor:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock my-image
```

If you don't want to building a new image you can use my prebuilt image: https://hub.docker.com/r/mdobak/docker-jenkins/